# How to convert to binary as string in code C

Tags: c

I am trying to convert int to binary as string but I can not.
Please help me. How to convert integer to binary, please tell me.

```
Input: 32
Output: 00100000
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char converttobinary(int n)
{
    int i;
    int a[8];
    char op;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        a[i] = n % 2;
        n = (n - a[i]) / 2;
    }
    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        op = strcat(op, a[i]);
    }
    return op;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    char str;
    n = 254;
    str = converttobinary(n);
    printf("%c", str);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So. what type is `op` and which values can it have? What is the return type of your function and which values can it return?

Comment: `op` is a single character, so you can't `strcat()` it.

Comment: Please tell me specifically. How to modify it.

Comment: You need to go back to your textbook or tutorial and study the difference between characters and strings.

Comment: There are lots of questions with solutions to this problem

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to modify your solution with minimal changes to make it work. There are elegant solutions to convert Integer to Binary for example using shift operators.

One of the main issue in the code was you were using character instead of character array.
i.e `char str;` instead of `char str[SIZE];` 
Also you were performing string operations on a single character. Additionally, iostream header file is for C++.

There is room for lot of improvements in the solution posted below (I only made your code work with minimal changes).

My suggestion is to make your C basics strong and approach this problem again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void converttobinary(int n, char *op)
{
    int i;
    int a[8];
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        a[i] = n % 2;
        n = (n - a[i]) / 2;
    }
    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        op[i]=a[i];
    }

}
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char str[8];
    n = 8;
    converttobinary(n,str);
    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf(" %d ",str[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: When is the string null-terminated?  Well, it isn't null-terminated, so it isn't actually a string — by definition, a string is null-terminated.  You could use `printf("%8.8s\n", str);` to safely print the byte array without spaces between the digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *rev(char *str)
{
    char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    char *saved = str;
    while(end > str)
    {
        int tmp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = tmp;
    }
    return saved;
}

char *tobin(char *buff, unsigned long long data)
{
    char *saved = buff;

    while(data)
    {
        *buff++ = (data & 1) + '0';
        data >>= 1;
    }
    *buff = 0;
    return rev(saved);
}

int main()
{

    char x[128];
    unsigned long long z = 0x103;
    printf("%llu is 0b%s\n", z, tobin(x, z));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code a little bit to make what you want,
the result of this code with

```
n = 10
```

is

```
00001010
```

In this code i shift the bits n positions of the imput and compare if there is 1 or 0 in this position and write a '1' if there is a 1 or a '0' if we have a 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void converttobinary(int n, char op[8]){
    int auxiliar = n;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        auxiliar = auxiliar >> i;
        if (auxiliar & 1 == 1){
            op[7-i] = '1';
        } else{
            op[7-i] = '0';
        }
        auxiliar = n;
    }

}

int main (void){
    int n = 10;
    int i;
    char op[8];

    converttobinary(n, op);

    for(i = 7; i > -1; i--){
        printf("%c",op[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The output 'string' isn't null terminated, so it isn't a string, and you can't safely print it with `%s`.  You could use `printf("%8.8s\n", op);` to print the byte-array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thats true i just fix it thanks :)